# Why does my Vue file cause a TS6504 error and ask me if I meant to "allowJs"?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a simple Vue 3 project that uses TypeScript and is giving the following error when I run `vue-tsc --noEmit`.

```
error TS6504: File '/proj/src/pages/Index.vue.__VLS_template.jsx' is a JavaScript file. Did you mean to enable the 'allowJs' option?
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation

error TS6504: File '/proj/src/pages/Index.vue.js' is a JavaScript file. Did you mean to enable the 'allowJs' option?
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation

error TS6504: File '/proj/src/pages/PassLayout.vue.__VLS_template.jsx' is a JavaScript file. Did you mean to enable the 'allowJs' option?
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation

error TS6504: File '/proj/src/pages/PassLayout.vue.js' is a JavaScript file. Did you mean to enable the 'allowJs' option?
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
```

The files in question `Index.vue` and `PassLayout.vue` do not have `<script>` sections; they're `<template>` only.

**PassLayout.vue**

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Without explicitly specify a `<script>` block with a the `lang="ts"` attribute, vue-tsc assumes the file is JavaScript instead of TypeScript.

Either set `"allowJs": true` in the `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Or add the following to any single-file components that don't have an explicit script block.

```
<script setup lang="ts"></script>
```